# Geographically Weighted Lasso (pkg = gwrr) - Error in W.i %*% X[-i, ] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r, lasso-regression, gwr

I am trying to do geographically weighted lasso (GWL) in packgae `gwrr`. But get this error:

```
 Error in W.i %*% X[-i, ] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

The code is: `> col.gwl <- gwl.est(NPb~NAl2O3, locs, df, "exp")`

When I checked the error, the answer online was about the factor/character in the dataframe. And also the matrix `as.matrix`. But the variables in my dataframe `df` are all `numeric`.

Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thanks a million!

Comment: Yes. It showed > class(locs)
[1] "matrix"

Comment: I'd suggest posting your data objects inside your code using the ```dput()``` function. This will aid [reproducibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which makes it easier for the community to help you.